# Передача запроса сервлету и jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Что-то вообще заплутался,ребята.Помогите,пожалуйста.Никак не могу понять следующие вещи по MVC на JAVA :

> 1.Все говорят,что пересылается запрос,но метод forward класса RequestDispatcher
>     пересылает и request и response.
>
> 2.Почему именно в request мы добавляем атрибуты?А почему не в response?
>
> 3.Почему не добавляют атрибуты в response?
>
> 4.Почему в jsp получаем атрибуты?

Да что тогда вообще такое атрибут - серверная переменная,которая существует во время запроса.(я говорю про контекст запроса).Но мне не достаточно этого.

Про response вообще ничего не слышно.При передаче запросов я ни разу еще не встречал,чтобы задействовали объект response в MVC.
Просто получают атрибуты от полученного запроса и отображают их.

Comment: Например,есть html(форма - Surname) ,  jsp и есть сервлет.html форма делает запрос на сервлет.Сервлет  взаимодействует с моделью,а потом нужно отобразить все это на jsp.Если запихывать в response , то прочитать поток,да еще разделить все по jsp - нереально.А вот атрибуты request могут содержать в себе имя атрибута и сам объект,что является дико удобно для отображения на jsp.Вообще,нужно стараться отделять логику от представления и я за это.

Answer (score 1):

1) forward пересылает запрос от одного ресурса на другой вместе с ответом первого

2) Добавляем, чтобы ресурс, который обрабатывает запрос имел параметры, которую можно отобразить, обработать и т.п. Запрашиваемый ресурс может положить в ответ стрим

3) Используютсястримы

4) Чтобы отображать, калкулировать и т.п.